# Weird deformities on surfaces with ender 3

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3

Today I noticed some weird holes/deformities on the surface of this simple usb holder I printed. Since I'm fairly new to 3d printing I have no idea what may be the cause of this problem

My printer is a Ender 3 (Marlin 2.0.3) and I'm using Cura for slicing.

Pics:

[image: Picture 01]
[image]

It would be a great help if someone could give me some pointers on how to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! I'm *pretty sure* this question has been answered before. You may want to search around the site a little bit and see.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned I'm new to 3D printing and searching is a bit difficult when I don't even know what the problem is called. I have seem plenty of posts on "blobs and zits", "under extrusion" and whatnots yet I couldn't find a similar distortion pattern. It would be really nice if anyone could tell me what I'm supposed to look for, give me a link to check or anything else...

Comment: Don't look at the patterns. These are warts. I'm betting the other question I posted as a duplicate might answer your question.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: I don't actually see any answer about the bumps/warts on the linked question.